# Localization in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, asp.net-core-localization

I am trying to implement localization for a Blazor WebAssembly app.
I followed the [example](https://github.com/pranavkm/LocSample) referred in the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#blazor-webassembly).
I created the .resx files as per the example but my Blazor WebAssembly app does only show the string for the default .resx file ignoring the .resx files for the individual cultures.
In the Documentation referred above I read:

> By default, Blazor's linker configuration for Blazor WebAssembly apps
>   strips out internationalization information except for locales
>   explicitly requested. For more information and guidance on controlling
>   the linker's behavior, see [Configure the Linker for ASP.NET Core
>   Blazor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/blazor/configure-linker?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-the-linker-for-internationalization).

Following this last link I tried adding the following under my project file `<PropertyGroup>`

```
<MonoLinkerI18NAssemblies>all</MonoLinkerI18NAssemblies>
```

However this doesn't seem to work and on my Blazor WebAssembly app I am not able to see the localized text, I can only see the text for the default .resx file.

Comment: Can you provide a repo for this so someone can take a look?

Comment: in development it shows the default , try to browse with another browser simultaneously with two browsers , the second browser will send culture info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed on the next release of Blazor, preview 4.
This has been confirmed by the author of the [example](https://github.com/pranavkm/LocSample) in a github [issue](https://github.com/pranavkm/LocSample/issues/1).
The article in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/globalization-localization?view=aspnetcore-3.1#blazor-webassembly) was published a little too early but this should be fixed shortly when the Blazor preview 4 is released.

Answer (score 0):

Starting from Blazor Web Assembly preview 4 localization works. This [article](https://www.soluling.com/Help/Blazor/Index.htm) shows how to localize a Web Assembly Blazor application.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use .resx files any more. They are a little huge because of their XML structure.

Try this plugin, it's just awesome and it uses YAML instead of XML which makes the file much lighter and also there is an online tool associated with it that let's you translate your files using Microsoft Translator and Azure.

https://akmultilanguages.azurewebsites.net

https://github.com/aksoftware98/multilanguages

Answer (score 0):

This project https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate has full localization for both WebAssembly and Server-side Blazor using the Microsoft.Extensions.Localization libraries. It does use Po files vs resx. Here is the documentation: https://blazor-boilerplate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstarts/localization.html

Comment: for wasm => System.InvalidOperationException: Blazor detected a change in the application's culture that is not supported with the current project configuration. To change culture dynamically during startup, set <BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData>true</BlazorWebAssemblyLoadAllGlobalizationData> in the application's project file.